# Check if edit is valid for database ms-access

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I want to be able to check if I can edit a cell in a database with a new object

Example method declaration:

`something.isValid(Object newObject, row, column);`

Example cases:

- If the editing cell stores an Number
  and I give it a String, the method
  will return false...
- If the editing
  cell has to be different than every
  other entry (unique) and the new object is the
  same as something else, the method
  will also return false....

My main goal...
I want to check a whole row, and if everything is valid, I will edit the whole row.

Right now, the only way I can find out if I can actually edit something is by actually editing it and seeing if I get an error.

edit://`Interface DatabaseMetaData` is a good method. Is there a SQL command method?

****edit://I feel like the resultsetmeta data is good enough. however, where is the `isUnique()` Method?** edit://isSigned() accomplishes this?
edit://So I just check if !isSigned() and isWritable(). What about database column conditions? For example... X has to be more than 3 characters...**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `Object`, but just use the type which is associated with the datatype in question. You can find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html) more detailed information about which Java object types you should be using for certain DB datatypes with among others this table:

[image]
<sub>(source: [oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jdbc/getstart/mapping.html#1004845))</sub>

Alternatively, you can use [`DatabaseMetaData#getColumns()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to figure the column information (column name, datatype, size, maxlength, nullable, etc).

There are lot of other methods which may be of use, e.g. [`getIndexInfo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getIndexInfo(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20boolean)) to figure all indexes, the [`getPrimaryKeys()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getPrimaryKeys(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to figure the PK's, the [`getExportedKeys()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getExportedKeys(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to figure the FK's, etcetera. Just poke a bit round in the whole [`DatabaseMetaData` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) to find that you need.

Comment: This was useful but I think ResultSetMetaData is easier. Thoughts?

Comment: It contains the same information. You only have to create/prepare a `Statement` and query a `ResultSet` first before you can get it. This makes not much sense. With just the `Connection` you can already get the `DatabaseMetaData`.

Comment: Getting `[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function` for a lot of things... but oh well :\

Comment: The ODBC bridge driver is indeed a pain in the ass. You can either go for [HXTT JDBC driver](http://www.hxtt.com/access.html) (costs $$$ tho) or replace MSAccess by a real DB server which ships with decent (and free) JDBC drivers.

Comment: Forced to use access :( 

I have everything but if it is required or unique. That is all I need left. I can just hard code it I guess...